# How can I use an array index as form name in foreach loop?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to generate a list of forms using a foreach loop.  The forms are just item names that use POST to pass their id to my controller so they can be updated.  I am using onclick="form.submit()" to get the action.

This works as expected when there is only one item in list.

```
@foreach($items as $item)
{{ Form::open(['url'=>'item/view', 'name'=>'itemView']) }}
{{ Form::hidden('id', $item->id ) }}
  <li><a href="#" onclick="itemView.submit()">{{ $item->name }}</a></li>
{{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
```

However, as soon as the are >1 items I get a 'itemView.submt is not a function' error.  I susoect this is because there are now duplicate form names.

QUESTION: How do I use the array index to make the form names unique?

I have tried this with no luck.

```
@foreach($items as $item)
{{ Form::open(['url'=>'item/view', 'name'=>'itemView[]']) }}
{{ Form::hidden('id', $item->id ) }}
  <li><a href="#" onclick="itemView[].submit()">{{ $item->name }}</a></li>
{{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
```

I am sure it's possible, not sure how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use function with `onclick`, for example:

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)
    {{ Form::open(['url'=>'item/view', 'name'=>'itemView[]']) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('id', $item->id ) }}
        <li><a href="#" onclick="submitForm({{ $key }})">{{ $item->name }}</a></li>
    {{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
```

But a better approach would be keeping all JS in JS files and to [not mix PHP and JS](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-put-js-and-css-in-blade-templates-and-do-not-put-any-html-in-php-classes) as I'm showing in my repo:

```
<a href="#" class="js_link">{{ $item->name }}</a></li>
```

And JS could look like this:

```
$('.js_link').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  Went your recco, keeping JS and PHP separated.  Works.